# 3 sets of wires what do I do?

Tags: light-fixture, ceiling-fan, old-house

I am installing a ceiling fan with a light kit which I have done before. But I’ve never had these many wires in the box. So what’s what? What goes to the which ones?

[image]

Brightened up
[image]

[image]

Brightened up
[image]

[image]

Comment: It's uually clearer if you examine them **before** you unhook whatever they were connected to before. Once they are all just disconnected wires, it's going to require considerable investigation to sort out which are doing what. Did you take any "before" pictures? If so, edit them in.

Comment: From just that picture, no one can tell.  Sometimes it is one power cable that also powers two other devices.  Or one power, one switch, and one to other device.  Test matching connections is not recommended.

Comment: When was the bare section of copper snipped off on the two pairs?  Did you do that or where they that way?

Comment: I added pictures of the before light fixture

Comment: Can you post picture of how the switch is wired?   There might be problem of switching neutral instead of hot/live/power.

Comment: Why do people "pose" the wires by disconnecting all of them and fanning them out like that?  That doesn't tell us a thing; the critical information is *how they were connected before*, and that info is destroyed by using that method.

Comment: You *are* planning to use a fan-rated box, right?

Comment: It's clearly too late now - but for future reference: **Don't do that!**. "That" being to disconnect everything and try to redo it all from first principals. Presumably the existing fixture worked as it was wired up - so *just use the same pair of wires for your new fixture*.

Answer (score 5):

There are a number of possibilities for each cable, including:

- Incoming power
- Switch loop
- Ongoing power to another device

In order to figure this out, you will need at a minimum a non-contact voltage tester like [this Klein](https://amzn.to/3oiidhr):

[image: Klein NCVT1P]

Verify that none of the wires are currently hot. Then turn on the breaker and check which wire(s) are hot. There should only be hot in one cable. If that's the case, mark that as "incoming power". *If you can't identify **incoming power**, stop and ask more questions*.

Check if there is anything else currently *not* working with the breaker on. There likely will be at least one light in another room or a receptacle somewhere. If you find that, good. Make sure the original switch is **off**. Turn off the breaker, connect the incoming power black and white to the matching wires on another cable with wire nuts or Wagos. Turn on the breaker. If the other light/receptacle now works, this cable is "ongoing power". If the other light/receptacle still does not work, turn off the breaker and connect "incoming power" to the other cable instead. Turn on the breaker. If the other light/receptacle now works then you have identified "ongoing power".  *If you can't identify ongoing power, **stop** to ask more questions*.

If you got this far, the remaining cable should be the switch loop. Connect as follows:

- Incoming power black, ongoing power black, switch loop white together. Mark the switch loop white with black electrical tape.
- Incoming power white, ongoing power white, fan/light white together.
- Switch loop black, fan/light hot (usually black but could be red or blue) together.

The switch will power *everything* in the fan/light at the same time. Which means you will control fan and light separately with either pull string switches (old style) or remote control (new style). You can't get separate wired wall switch control of fan and light without a new cable.

Comment: This all gets done after you've installed a ceiling fan rated box.

Comment: Thank you so much this worked perfect. Everything you described was exactly how it was. It took me a while to figure out which fixtures were off but I got it. Thank you again!!